# How to send file using the Gmail chat?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

Can I send files using the Gmail web chat? That feature exist in that chat? What are my options in case not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time Google has two chat services that could be used inline with Gmail web interface: [Google Chat](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/159495?hl=en) and [Google Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2944865?hl=en).

You could use Hangouts to send photos/pictures [1,2] but no other kind of files. Instead you could send files by a Gmail message up to 25MB [3] or uploading the file to Google Drive or another file hosting service and use Chat/Hangouts to send the link to the file.

**References**
1. [About Google Chat](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/159495?hl=en)
2. [Share and delete your photos from Hangouts messages and Google Voice MMS - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115410?hl=en)
3. [Add attachments - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I still don't know after read what you wrote  how "You could use them to send photos/pictures but no other kind of files"? Specifically Google Chat. Thanks again. "Pictures in the chat window - Chat Help" is to show just profile pic, no to allow send pics over the chat.

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated the answer.

Comment: So no way to send any kind of file using Google Chat?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't.